# What is the term for drawing wireframes which are drawn before drawing the actual object?

Tags: drawing, terminology

[image: Wireframe plant drawing]

<sup>Image of pitcher plant from [drawbox.com](http://drawabox.com/lesson/3)</sup>

I wish to learn how to visualize and draw wireframes like that for any object.
I searched Google with term *"drawing wireframes"* but didn't get what I was looking for.

What term should I search in Google to learn how to visualize and draw the kind of wireframe shown in that link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drawing in your link is a **sketch** with **contour lines** (*the circles that define the 3D quality of the drawing.*)

This style is often used in Product Design - so I suggest searching for "**Product Design sketching**" or "**Industrial Design sketching**"; There is a wealth of information in that field on this way of drawing. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Those are your **construction lines**.

Be advised that this term is also used for 3D modeling, and you may need to filter CAD out of any web searches.

They can also be called **guidelines**.

When drawing figures, they're often called **mannequins**.

These terms can be a bit generic. What will help find tutorials or guides is a combination of `construction drawing` + your art type, such as `figure` or `still life`.

You may find success looking at contour lines, as another answer suggests, but [contour lines](https://www.google.com/search?q=contour+lines+drawing&source=lnms&tbm=isch) typically have a different connotation in drawing. Contours describe the *visible* surface and outlines. They don't describe the wireframe/unseen surfaces as seen in the tutorial you mentioned. Just be wary in looking for contour drawings, as that will lead you to a different type of exercise/drawing technique.

Answer (score 3):

A book that gives great instructions for planning out guidelines and mannequins for drawings is [Preston Blair's book "Cartoon Animation".](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560100842)  Here's [a pdf](http://desgraff.com/downloads/prestonblair.pdf) of the whole book.

His book is centered more around drawing in a traditional Disney 2D cartoonish style, but his ideas apply to all styles of figure drawing, really.  Here are some images to give you a sense of the frames instructed in that book.

[image] [image]
[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question posted. They're asking for the proper terminology to use